# LazyLoad mesmo colocando .include(t => t.Model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lazy-loading

Estou tendo o erro:

> Exception Details: System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext
>   instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations
>   that require a connection.

Quando faço a chamada:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cliente.Url)
```

Essa view recebe uma model chamada boleto, que contém Clientes;

Estou fazendo na **controller**:

```
        using (var BolGeral = new BoletoGeral())
        {
            IEnumerable<boleto> clientesFiltrados = BolGeral.GerarIDCImpressaoMensal();

            return View(clientesFiltrados);
        }
//se não uso o Dispose ele funciona, pois ai ele ainda está conectado e consegue recuperar os valores.
```

A Função **BolGeral.GerarIDCImpressaoMensal();**

```
    public IEnumerable<boleto> GerarIDCImpressaoMensal()
    {
        var DataRef = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);

        var IdClientesSemBoleto = (from cli in db.Clientes
                                   join bol in db.Boletos on cli.ClienteId equals bol.ClienteId
                                   where bol.DataReferencia == DataRef && cli.Status == 4 && cli.Convenio == 0
                                   select cli.ClienteId);

        var clientes = db.Boletos
            .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Distinct().Contains(s.ClienteId))
            .Where(i => i.Cliente.Status == 4 && i.Cliente.Convenio == 0);

        //fazendo o distinct
        IEnumerable<boleto> clientesFiltrados = clientes
              .Include(i => i.Cliente) // Aqui está o include
              .GroupBy(customer => customer.ClienteId)
              .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(o => o.Cliente.Url).ToList();

        return clientesFiltrados;
    }
```

Veja que o    `IEnumerable<boleto> clientesFiltrados`  tem um include para não fazer LazyLoad, **mas porque então da erro como se estivesse fazendo o LazyLoad, quando na controller faço o disposed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A declaração de `Include` deve vir antes de `Where`. A montagem do `IQueryable` pode ficar errada se você montar os `Where` e depois usar o `Include`:

```
var clientes = db.Boletos
        .Include(i => i.Cliente) // Aqui está o include
        .Where(s => !IdClientesSemBoleto.Distinct().Contains(s.ClienteId))
        .Where(i => i.Cliente.Status == 4 && i.Cliente.Convenio == 0);
```

Procure também materializar a lista de clientes em memória antes de montar o `Where` porque o Entity Framework tenta resolver a lista em sentença, e isto pode gerar erros:

```
var listaDeClientesSemBoleto = IdClientesSemBoleto.Distinct();
var clientes = db.Boletos
        .Include(i => i.Cliente) // Aqui está o include
        .Where(s => !listaDeClientesSemBoleto.Contains(s.ClienteId))
        .Where(i => i.Cliente.Status == 4 && i.Cliente.Convenio == 0);
```

Por fim:

```
var clientesFiltrados = clientes
          .GroupBy(customer => customer.ClienteId)
          .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault())
          .OrderBy(o => o.Cliente.Url)
          .ToList();
```